# How to use SQLite's "whereClause" inside update method

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm dealing with an sqlite db in android application.
To update a row in the db I use method of SQLiteDatabase object "update"

```
SQLiteDatabase.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

But here a confusion, how "whereClause" should look like?
Assume I have these values for update.

```
values.put("name", appInfo.getName());
values.put("package_name", appInfo.getPackageName());
values.put("version_name", appInfo.getVersionName());
```

I want to update a row where package_mane column equal to "com.mynamespace.db". How "whereClause" should be written here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `whereClause` should look like this:

```
String whereClause = "package_mane = ?"; // package_name perhaps?
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"com.mynamespase.db"};
```

String from `whereArgs` are used to substitute `?` in `whereClause`.

Answer (score 8):

```
db.update("table", values, "package_name = ?", new String[]{"com.mynamespase.db"});
```

Another example:

```
db.update("table", values, "package_name = ? and other_field = ?", new String[]{"com.mynamespase.db", "test"});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use it like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase.update(table, "package_name=?", new String[] { "com.mynamespace.db" });
```

and prevent other problems and cache inefficiencies if you concat the string.

Answer (score 2):

```java
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "package_name=com.mynamespase.db", null);

// or

String[] args = { "com.mynamespase.db" };
db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, "package_name=?", args);
```